# Why is my ExtJS form not submitting?

Tags: javascript, extjs, submit

I'm using ExtJS to pop up a window with a simple edit form, but on pressing the submit button, no XHR call is made and I get a `this.form.el.dom is undefined` error reported in the console.

Here's my code:

```
var myNameSpace = new function(){
    var editForm, editWindow;

    this.init = function(){

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/server/action.php',
            success: function(result){
                console.log('ajax is working ok');  // I get this
            }
        });

        editForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            width:450,
            autoHeight: true,
            header : false,
            items:  [{
                name: 'color', 
                fieldLabel: 'Color', 
                xtype: 'textfield', 
                value: 'blue'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text:"Submit",
                scope: this,  // tried without this, too
                handler: function(){
                    // editForm.getForm().getValues() returns normal values
                    editForm.getForm().submit({
                        url: '/server/action.php',
                        success: function(form, action) {
                            console.log('Yes! Success!');  // I don't get this
                        },
                        failure: function(form, action) {
                            console.log('failed.');  // I don't get this
                        }
                    });
                    editWindow.close();  // works
                    console.log('the form is now closed'); // I get this
                }
            }]
        });

        editWindow = new Ext.Window(
        {
            title:'Enter your color',
            autoWidth: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            modal: true,
            items: editForm,
            closeAction: 'hide'
        });
        editWindow.show();
    };

};

Ext.onReady(function () {
    myNameSpace.init();
});
```

Any light on the subject will be greatly appreciated and profusely upvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to say that the issue is asynchonous nature of form submital. You form closes before the response is received from the Ajax submit event. Try moving your `editWindow.close()` line inside the success processing block.

Comment: Same thing happened to me.